# AWS api gateway setting custom domain

Tags: subdomain, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I'm using the API Gateway service to manage my spring boot resources. I want to point the gateway to my sub-domain. I tried adding it to alias in Route 53 but it does not work. There's an option in the API Gateway console which asks for my domain and some credentials. I don't know if a sub-domain can work and what should i add to certificate input. Probably it is asking for an SSL certificate and I am ready to purchase one, but before i do that, i want to be sure that it accepts sub-domains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `API Gateway` supports subdomains. You can try with self-signed certificate and see the options.

See the official documentation on using [Custom Domain Names in API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html).

Comment: Thank you. It works. I'd like u to take a look at this also. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32524305/5018624.  Thanks a lot