# Setting cookies for subdomain

Tags: cookies, spring-boot, subdomain

i'm making a web app in a restful way.
For my client side i'm using angularJs, the same is hosted at - lets say - 
https://domain.com

My backend is built on spring boot and i call all the resources from a subdomain - lets say - 
https://xyz.domain.com

Now when a user logs in , the backend sends an http only cookie to the client. 
I can see the cookie in response header but its not being set in the browsers cookie.

After a bit of research, i have tried sending cookie with domain = .domain.com 
but that didnt work either.

Is there a way i can set cookie coming from xyz.domain.com for my client side at domain.com

(Note - i'm not using www.domain.com )

Any help or clue would be great.

Thank you for going through my question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're describing is related to cross domain cookie policies. I don't know your exact use-case, but looking at `CORS` and `P3P` headers should give you a good start. As an option, you can try setting your cookie manually via Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Making CORS working isn't enough, you also need to enable withCredentials in angular.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Example:

```
angular.module('example', []).config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```